# Как запретить изменение поля после изменения django

Tags: django, django-admin

Как сделать так, чтобы после первого изменения поля или заполнения всего объекта модели все его поля стали только для чтения, чтобы нельзя было потом изменить?
Пусть есть модель Vyazka

```
class Vyazka(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(MaterialTaked, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Взятая старшим масса материала')
    mass_taked = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Масса, которую дал старший', default=0)
    mass_finish = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Готовая масса после вязки', blank=True, null=True, help_text='Заполнить после того, как работник сделал вязку')
    count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество готовой модели', blank=True, null=True,help_text='Заполнить после того, как работник сделал вязку')
    material_given_to = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Рабочий по вязке', related_name='employees')
    mass_brak = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Масса брака', default=0, help_text='Заполнить после того, как работник сделал вязку')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата передачи материала')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата последнего изменения')
```

Суть модели в том, что работнику дается материал и сначала заполняются поля
material, mass_taked, material_given_to

И в админ панели после их заполнения эти поля должны стать только для чтения, чтобы их нельзя было уже поменять.

[image: Здесь еще не все поля заполнены]

А после заполнения всех полей до конца - все его поля, должны стать неизменяемыми

[image: После полного заполнения их нельзя уже поменять]
Для примера я просто убрал поле

```
list_editable = ['mass_finish', 'count', 'mass_brak']
```

Но нужно чтобы это делалось автоматически

Если можно на любом примере.

Comment: не понятно. Дайте пример использования

Comment: Изменил и дополнил